# OpenERP create & write methods at once

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Here is my error when i'm going to create records.please advice me where is the missing point.?

```
  File "/home/bellvantage/Documents/openerp-7.0/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/bpl.py", line 394, in create
    self.write(cr, uid, [id], {'name': name}, context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/extensions.py", line 129, in getquoted
    pobjs = [adapt(o) for o in self._seq]
ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'builtin_function_or_method'
2013-04-26 06:14:07,719 5739 INFO demo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [26/Apr/2013 06:14:07] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

relevant line in my code is like this

```
def create(self, cr, uid, values, context=None):
    name = 'CheckRoll No : ' + str(values['checkroll_no']) + ' & Gang No : ' + str(values['gang_no'])
    self.write(cr, uid, [id], {'name': name}, context)
    return True
```

error comes and shows that my write method is incorrect.seems some parameter missing by me.
needs your advices to implement module
thanks..

**EDITED**

Now error like below

```
  File "/home/bellvantage/Documents/openerp-7.0/openerp-7/openerp/addons/bpl/bpl.py", line 395, in create
    res = super('bpl.work.offer',self).create(cr,uid,values,context=context)
TypeError: must be type, not str
2013-04-26 07:58:43,452 6947 INFO demo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [26/Apr/2013 07:58:43] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

here shows my fields in model class

```
'name': fields.char('Name', size=50),
'checkroll_no': fields.integer('Checkroll No'),
'gang_no': fields.integer('Gang'),
```

here shows **values** when i debug (at super.create() time),

```
dict: {'selected_tea_workers_line_ids': [[5, False, False], [0, False, {'worker_emp_no': '1000', 'worker_id': 
 1, 'tea_line_worker_id': False, 'is_selected': False}]], 'user_id': False, 'is_confirmed': False, 
 'date_of_offer': '2013-04-26', 'bpl_division_id': 1, 'work_type': 'tea', 'checkroll_no': 10, 'name': 
 'CheckRoll No : 10 & Gang No : 100', 'selected_rubber_workers_line_ids': [[5, False, False], [0, False, 
 {'worker_emp_no': '1001', 'worker_id': 2, 'rubber_line_worker_id': False, 'is_selected': False}]], 
 'work_update_id': False, 'field_no': 15, 'selected_sundry_workers_line_ids': [], 'payment_type': 
 'normal_work', 'gang_no': 100, 'total_workers': 0, 'no_of_workers': 0, 'norm': 15, 
 'selected_other_workers_line_ids': [], 'bpl_estate_id': 1, 'select_by': 'by_name'}
```

now its worked. thanks AnomA

**Last Edited**

```
def create(self, cr, uid, values, context=None):
    name = 'CheckRoll No = ' + str(values['checkroll_no']) + ' & Gang No = ' + str(values['gang_no'])
    values.update({'name': name})
    return super(bpl_work_offer,self).create(cr,uid,values,context=context)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you are doing wrong. You are trying to write to a record that is not created.Also I dont think you need to use write in this case.

```
class bpl_abc(osv.osv)
    _inherit = 'bpl.work.offer'
    def create(self, cr, uid, values, context=None):
        name = 'CheckRoll No : ' + str(values['checkroll_no']) + ' & Gang No : ' + str(values['gang_no'])
        values.update({'name': name})
        res = super('bpl_abc',self).create(cr,uid,values,context=context)
        return res
bpl_abc()
```

Please keep in mind that create function in openerp always return an id of the newly created record.

Comment: what error? please check the values in checkroll_no and gang_no in values.

Comment: Sorted AnomA
thanks.i missed model class and give it as string :-)

Answer (score -2):

May be because 'write' method is the built-in method

EX:

```
with open("a.txt","r+") as f:
    f.write("sometext")
```

Don't use self.write as write is the built-in method on 'file' object

Comment: seems issue with [id].need to get id of self object

Comment: you have defined "write" method and using that over here, What I want you is to rename the "write" method of yours

Comment: thanks Rajesh.
yep.need to overide that write and update values when my create function called.thats my requirement.how to do that.?